# Dynamic array of MPI_Datatype

Tags: c, mpi

Is the following valid :

```
int x; 
scanf("%d", &x);    //say 3

MPI_Datatype *sub ;
sub = calloc(x,sizeof(MPI_Datatype));
```

Now can we use `sub[0], sub[1], sub[2]` as MPI_Datatypes ?

Comment: What is `MPI_Datatype` meaning what data does it hold? How would we know if this is correct without knowing what it will hold?

Comment: What I am asking is : Is the above equivalent to saying : `MPI_Datatype sub[3];`

Comment: It is apparently not.

Comment: Please check this link : [link] https://books.google.co.in/books?id=x79puJ2YkroC&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=what+is+sizeof(MPI_Datatype)+?&source=bl&ots=55JQpt0JE6&sig=YO0r1GkvdkhmGNZNqlJ8isSdmLA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEoQ6AEwB2oVChMIuM298JX1xgIVyLsUCh3FXApX#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20sizeof(MPI_Datatype)%20%3F&f=false

Comment: For the commentators: this question concerns the construction of MPI derived datatypes like subarrays, vectors, contiguous data-types etc. Why I am asking this question is because I need to dynamically set the datatypes of type 'MPI_Type_subarray( )' for various levels of _Multigrid_ method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
MPI_Datatype *sub = calloc(x, sizeof(MPI_Datatype));
```

and

```
MPI_Datatype sub[x] = { 0 };
```

are mostly equivalent when it comes to using `sub` as an array afterwards. The `{ 0 }` initialiser is needed to match the memory zeroing properties of `calloc()`. The difference is that `&sub` will not be the same in both cases: it equates the address of the pointer variable itself in the former case and the address of the data in the latter case. So always use `&sub[0]` to get a pointer to the beginning of the array data.

If you enable C99 mode of your compiler, e.g. with `-std=c99`, and if you expect `x` not to be a very large value so that the array of `MPI_Datatype` would fit on the stack, then you could simply use:

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);
MPI_Datatype sub[x];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that answers my question completely.